# Git diff — "no such path in the working tree"

Tags: git, git-diff

Everything in my git repo works perfectly fine except when I modify a file and try to do a git diff, I get this error —

```
fatal: 1b9cc4afe763304c97f95bc8e272ebce7a034e59: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
```

- Operating System: `MAC OS 10.13.6`
- Git Version: `git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)`
- This is my repo: `https://github.com/tusharmath/tusharmath.github.io`
- branch name: `develop`

Just clone and editing the file doesn't let me perform a `git diff`.

**UPDATE**

I tried using the Github Desktop APP, and everything works fine there.

Comment: not is problem with me, do you try re-clone it?

Comment: It seems `1b9cc4afe763304c97f95bc8e272ebce7a034e59` was interpreted as a path. Did you place `--` with spaces around before the hash, if you were running a `git diff` command?

Comment: I only wrote `git diff`

Comment: @ChienNguyen I did. I think its because of my git installation. Something that I might have messed up.

Answer (score 1):

> I think its because of my git installation. Something that I might have messed up. –

Try first and update your Git to the latest 2.20.1 version, making sure it is in `/usr/local/git/bin/git`

As [explained here](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-git-macos/):

> If you have Xcode already installed and have installed command line tools then you already have Git, probably an older version which is distributed with Xcode, this is installed in a path that takes precedence at:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/git
> ```

So make sure your PATH will select your Git first:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/git:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I am on  a mac os

Comment: @Tushar OK, I have rewritten the answer to address a Git installation on MacOS.